# How do I avoid shadowed variable warnings when using Enums in recent eslint?

Tags: typescript, enums, eslint

Consider the following file:

```
export enum WorkshopOrderByType {
  featuredAt = "featuredAt",
  updatedAt = "updatedAt",
  createdAt = "createdAt",
  workshopStartDate = "workshopStartDate",
  attendingBatchStart = "attendingBatchStart",
}
```

The most recent eslint will complain that:

> 'WorkshopOrderByType' is already declared in the upper scope.

This is described in [the following eslint issue](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/325).

The [`no-identifier-enum-member`](https://github.com/oigewan/typescript-eslint/blob/96872c35c6d32825e1a3bbd4a5337837355270e8/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-identifier-enum-member.md) and [`prefer-literal-enum-member`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/pull/1898) are apparently related to this, and there was talk of creating an exception for Enums as an option for `no-shadow`.

**But, as of now - how do I refactor the code above to fix the `no-shadow` warning?**

Answer (score 3):

The error comes from [using the `no-shadow` rule instead of  `@typescript-eslint/no-shadow`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2733).

We added the:

```
"@typescript-eslint/no-shadow": "error",
```

And removed the corresponding

```
"no-shadow": ...
```

rule which removed the warnings.